# Trash folder in the wrong location with bound partitions

Tags: ntfs, fstab, trash, bind

My NTFS partition is mounted as follows:

`/dev/sdb1 /mnt/dos ntfs permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,uid=1000,umask=0 0 0`

I bound several folders to my home as follows:

```
/mnt/dos/Books /home/me/Books none bind 0 0
/mnt/dos/Music /home/me/Music none bind 0 0
/mnt/dos/Videos /home/me/Videos none bind 0 0
/mnt/dos/Pictures /home/me/Pictures none bind 0 0
```

Whenever a file is deleted in Nautilus from these bound folders it gets sent to the `.Trash-1000` located under the bound folder rather than the one in my home directory. I do not see the contents of these additional trash folders when I click on the Trash icon, so they are practically inaccessible. I do not believe this is the intended behavior.

FYI: [Unresolved thread on ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1081494).

Comment: rm never moves files to Trash. What heppen when you want to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [long-standing bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=604015) that, as of writing, [has not been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/594674).

Answer (score 0):

Add `umask=0` at the end of mount-options line. I've tested it with ntfs partition in my PC. It should make nautilus delete folder to `.Trash-1000` folder.

The line should now becomes like this

```
/dev/sdb1 /mnt/dos ntfs permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,uid=1000,umask=0  0 0
```

Replace the `uid=1000` with the original uid of your user. You can see it by using `id -u` command.

Comment: This gives me a "Cannot move file to trash, do you want to delete immediately?" error. What are your Trash folder's permissions and groups? Mine are all `root`.

Comment: My `.Trash-1000` folder's owner is Me (uid=1000)

Comment: @Emre also add the actual uid before umask by using `uid=XXXX` format. for me it is `uid=1000`

Comment: That did not work. Something is still different between our configurations. Can you help me troubleshoot?

Comment: Let me know the output of your `id -u` and the line of `/etc/fstab`. ?

Comment: 1000 and `/dev/sdb1 /mnt/dos ntfs permissions,locale=en_US.utf8,uid=1000,umask=0 0 0`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4833/discussion-between-anwar-and-emre)

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.